# как полученные данные из интернета вывести списком?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как полученные данные из интернета вывести списком в виджете ListView? Выводит только первую строку. Я не могу создать коллекцию, в моем примере строка закоментирована

```
List<Data> ara = snapshot.data;
```

Далее полный код и скриншот. 
**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// #1 класс содержащий данные из сетевого запроса
class Data {

 final int userId;
 final int id;
 final String title;
 final bool completed;

 Data({
  @required this.userId,
  @required this.id,
  @required this.title,
  @required this.completed,
 });

 factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Data(
   userId: json['userId'] as int,
   id: json['id'] as int,
   title: json['title'] as String,
   completed: json['completed'] as bool,
  );
 }

}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _url;
 Future<Data> _futureData;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  _futureData = _funConvert(_url);

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 //#2 метод конвертирует ответ сервера из JSON в коллекцию Map
 Future<Data> _funConvert(String url) async {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
   return Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
   throw Exception('failed to load');
  }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<Data>(
       future: _futureData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.hasData) {
          //List<Data> ara = snapshot.data;
          return ListView(
           children: [
            Text('${snapshot.data.userId} ${snapshot.data.id} ${snapshot.data.title} ${snapshot.data.completed}'),
           ],
          );
         } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
         } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
         }
        },
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` только дает один элемент)) Вам нужно: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`

Comment: + не `Future<Data>`, а `Future<List<Data>>` будет. И сам метод `_funConvert` тоже поменяется...

Comment: Уважаемый MiT! Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Уважаемый MiT! Огромное Вам спасибо! return Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); выдает ошибку, после изменений. Как здесь быть?

Comment: `List<Data>.from(json.decode(response.body).map((v) => Data.fromJson(v)));` https://app.quicktype.io?share=5G76vBQiDqlNIk0QcbD1

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, кому-то понадобится **полный ответ**, как вывести все данные списком. Что бы помещалось все на экране, не стал выводить 'title'. Здесь будет один общий скриншот и два варианта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 вариант, его подсказал **участник форума MiT**, по его подсказке я написал код. 

запрос по этому адресу возвращает список всех элементов

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/
```

***main.dart***

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// #1 класс содержащий данные из сетевого запроса
class Data {

 final int userId;
 final int id;
 final String title;
 final bool completed;

 Data({
  @required this.userId,
  @required this.id,
  @required this.title,
  @required this.completed,
 });

 factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  Data(
   userId: json['userId'] == null ? null : json['userId'] as int,
   id: json['id'] == null ? null : json['id'] as int,
   title: json['title'] == null ? null : json['title'] as String,
   completed: json['completed'] == null ? null : json['completed'] as bool,
  );

}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _url;
 Future<List<Data>> _futureData;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

  //запрос по этому адресу возвращает список всех элементов
  _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';

  _futureData = _dataFromJson(_url);

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 // #2 метод конвертирует ответ сервера из JSON в коллекцию
 Future<List<Data>> _dataFromJson(String url) async {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
   return List<Data>.from(json.decode(response.body).map((v) => Data.fromJson(v)));
  } else {
   throw Exception('failed to load');
  }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
       future: _futureData,
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
         return ListView(
          children: List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (index) =>
           Text('${snapshot.data[index].userId}  ${snapshot.data[index].id}  ${snapshot.data[index].completed}')
          ),
         );
        } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
         return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        } else {
         return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
        }
       },
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

2 вариант, почти такой пример я видел на сайте Flutter, в нем нужно подключить **import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';** что бы использовать функцию **compute()** 

запрос по этому адресу возвращает список всех элементов

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/
```

***main.dart***

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// #1 класс содержащий данные из сетевого запроса
class Data {

 final int userId;
 final int id;
 final String title;
 final bool completed;

 Data({
  @required this.userId,
  @required this.id,
  @required this.title,
  @required this.completed,
 });

 factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  Data(
   userId: json['userId'] == null ? null : json['userId'] as int,
   id: json['id'] == null ? null : json['id'] as int,
   title: json['title'] == null ? null : json['title'] as String,
   completed: json['completed'] == null ? null : json['completed'] as bool,
  );

}

// #2 метод конвертирует ответ сервера из JSON в коллекцию List<Data>.
List<Data> dataFromJson(String responseBody) {
 final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
 return parsed.map<Data>((json) => Data.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

// #3 метод запускает метод #2 в отдельном изолированном потоке
Future<List<Data>> isolateDataFromJson(http.Client client) async {
 //запрос по этому адресу возвращает список всех элементов
 final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
 final response = await client.get(url);
 return compute(dataFromJson, response.body);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
       future: isolateDataFromJson(http.Client()),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
         return ListView(
          children: List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (index) =>
           Text('${snapshot.data[index].userId}  ${snapshot.data[index].id}  ${snapshot.data[index].completed}')
          ),
         );
        } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
         return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        } else {
         return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
        }
       },
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```